# Excecute function in oracle 10g

Tags: php, oracle10g

The below function should send an SMS when it is executed. Actually I did not work with Oracle for almost more than 8 years and using MySQL. Can some one help me how to execute the below function in Oracle. I have installed Oracle 10g and created this function but do not know how to save it and execute it. `sendsms.php` is a page in my server which responsible to take the post from the Oracle function data and send the message.

```
Create or replace function Send_MSG
    ( 
    P_User_Name in varchar2,
    P_Password  in varchar2,
    P_numbers   in varchar2,
    P_Sender    in varchar2,
    P_msg       in varchar2,
    P_dateSend  in varchar2 default 0, 
    P_timeSend  in varchar2 default 0,
    P_deleteKey in varchar2,
    P_msgKey    in varchar2
    )
    Return varchar2 is
    Begin

    Return 'http://www.mywebsite.com/sendsms.php?mobile='||P_User_Name||'&'||'password='||P_Password||'&'||'numbers='||P_numbers||'&'||'sender='||P_sender||'&'||'msg='||xx_unicode(P_msg)||'&'||'dateSend='||nvl(P_dateSend,0)||'&'||'timeSend='||nvl(P_timeSend,0)||'&'||'msgId='||P_msgKey||'&'||'applicationType=24';


    End Send_MSG;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want oracle to go to that url and fetch the output from it, then just change your return line to:

```
return utl_http.request(
'http://www.mywebsite.com/sendsms.php?mobile='||P_User_Name||'&'||'password='||P_Password||'&'||'numbers='||P_numbers||'&'||'sender='||P_sender||'&'||'msg='||xx_unicode(P_msg)||'&'||'dateSend='||nvl(P_dateSend,0)||'&'||'timeSend='||nvl(P_timeSend,0)||'&'||'msgId='||P_msgKey||'&'||'applicationType=24');
```

p.s. if you need to set a proxy, you need to call

```
utl_http.set_proxy('your-proxy:port', '');
```

prior to the return.